Why is it possible to avoid having a passport stamped when traveling from Monaco to Switzerland?
After hearing that his wife Naomi’s aunt Emma had died in London, Jordan Belfort
contacted Jean, a Swiss banker, about Aunt Emma’s account which was holding his money.
Jean advised him to come to Switzerland as soon as possible to complete the
process of saving that money, so Jordan Belfort directed his ship captain Ted:

Jordan Belfort: We're going to Monaco so that we can drive to Switzerland. so they
don't stamp our passports. Take care of business here, we'll drive
back to Monaco, take a flight over to London to catch the funeral
and be in New York in three fucking business days!

Why is it possible to avoid having a passport stamped when traveling from Monaco to Switzerland?

Switzerland is in the Schengen zone and a member of it.
The idea is that travel within the (29 country member) zone is borderless and you will not get your passport  stamped (or even looked at).
Vatican City, San Marino and Monaco are special cases - they are not members of the Schengen Area but still have open borders with the area, so you can drive through without getting your passport stamped.

When visiting Monaco, there is no passport control except of when coming from a Schengen country. Visitors were previously able to get souvenir passport stamps at a state tourism office. Official passports are no longer stamped as this may cause difficulties with validity.
en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Monaco


Travelling within Schengen there is no need to stamp, in fact you would be hard pressed to find somebody at the border crossing. Entering or leaving Schengen third country passports need to be stamped at the point of entry/exit.
https://swissforum.co.uk/t/british-passport-stamping-within-the-schengen-zone/1337/4

Also: https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g188045-i336-k11118950-Passport_stamps-Switzerland.html
The only entry exit stamps would be at the airport in Monaco.
So, relating to the movie, they fly into Monaco, get stamped at the airport, then travel freely to Switzerland without having their passports even looked at, conduct business there, then drive back to Monaco, again without being stamped, then fly out of Monaco with an exit stamp at the airport (and on to London).

Switzerland didn't join the Schengen Treaty until 2008. The film takes place in the 1990s, does it not? At least that's when the real story happened.

Yes, i noticed about that too, but from personal experience, for a long time before Switzerland joined, as long as your plates on your vehicle were 'local', you could drive through without being checked anyway. For a long time you could just hang your passport outside and they (if there were anyone at the border posts) would just wave you through, without you stopping. 90s Europe was relaxed for quite a while.

There is no airport in Monaco, only an heliport. People flying in use the nearby Nice airport (NCE) in France instead, and either drive, take the train, or use a helicopter between the two. I believe there would be stamps if you arrived by sea rather than by air, which seems to be the case here. So there would be no stamps about France or Switzerland, but there would likely be stamps about entering (and then exiting) Monaco.

@JörgWMittag as blobbymcblobby wrote, border controls in many places in Europe were very relaxed way before Schengen. Checks in trains were limited, checks at land crossings varied between limited and non-existent depending on the crossing. Along probably 99% of the FR/CH border you could cross it without even noticing. I've crossed that border hundreds of times when I was a kid in the 80s and I don't think I've ever had my passport stamped (and very rarely looked at). Hundreds of thousands of people cross that border every day to go to work, they just can't check or stamp everyone.

@jcaron good catch on re flying entry exit in Monaco, forgot about that.

I flew into Switzerland from the UK many times between 2000 and 2006 without any stamps in my passport. Some trips I'd be staying in a hotel over on the German or French side of the border and walk/tram/train to where I was working in Basel on a daily basis without needing a stamp. I had more hassle getting back into the UK when I went home at the end of each trip.

@JörgWMittag there was also a tram all the way back in 1986 that crossed from Switzerland into France with no border controls: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_10_(BLT)
